# How would you play sounds from a microcontroller (STM32 etc.)?

Tags: audio, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

For example, how would a washing machine play a specific sound (MP3 or WAV or whatever) when finished? Which external components are needed?

I know this is a really vague question but I could not find any real solutions except some kind of MP3 player module which seems to be more "end-user friendly" instead of being used programmatically (skip and pause buttons).

Comment: You need a resistor and caoacitor. LP filter. PWM generation.

Comment: that is the simplest

Comment: you can use DAC

Comment: Your question must include CODE to use the `arduino` tag.  Read the tag description and add code or remove the tag.  And this is not a design/brainstorming site.  Ask a specific code-based question or delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various beeps can be made simply by toggling a pin, but I assume your are looking for something more melodious, and without using a sound synthesiser.

For short sound bites: you can store them in (external) memory and play them through a DAC, if your MCU has one. I put a basic implementation of this for SAMD21G-based Arduinos [here](https://github.com/ocrdu/Arduino_SAMD21_Audio_Player); the idea is the same for all MCUs that have a DAC. If your MCU doesn't have a DAC, you can use an external one, or make a "poor man's DAC" by using PWM and low-pass filtering the output.

Another option is creating an I<sup>2</sup>S stream from stored samples and send them to an external amplifier (module) that accepts I<sup>2</sup>S. It helps when your MCU has an I<sup>2</sup>S peripheral.

For longer sounds, your best bet is probably playing them from a MCU-controlled MP3-player, because you need the SD-card storage or a similarly large storage anyway for large sound files.

In all cases, you'll need an external amplifier and speaker.